# Websphere ejb pool size

Tags: ejb-3.0, websphere-8, pool

I have few questions regarding ejb pool size in websphere.

1. It is mentioned in the documentation here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rejb_ecnt.html that the default ejb pool size is 50 - 500.

My question is, is it for all the ejbs together or is it per ejb? What i understood is, it is per ejb. Am I right?

2. Is there any tool to monitor the ejb pool size in websphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A1.** You are correct, a pool exists per EJB and the default for each pool will be minimum 50 / maximum 500. The link you provided does show how to use the **com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.poolSize** property to change the pool size for individual EJBs or change the default that applies to all types. In all cases, there is a pool per EJB.

**A2.** The EJB pool size may be monitored using the Tivoli Performance Viewer. The EJB counters available are documented here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rprf_datacounter1.html

And the specific ones relevant to the EJB pool are : RetrieveFromPoolCount, RetrieveFromPoolSuccessCount, ReturnsToPoolCount, ReturnsDiscardCount, DrainsFromPoolCount, DrainSize, PooledCount